# Organise a data frame for analysis by stacking columns and repeating others

Tags: r, dataframe, stack

I am trying to get `newdf` from ``olddf`. Basically, I want to duplicate and stack columns` A`and`B`to allow for columns`C`and`D```` to be stacked in a single column. Sorry for the bad explanation, essentially, I am stacking `C` and `D` into a single column and need to repeat `A` and `B` to account for the repetitions, thank you.

```
olddf <- data.frame('A' = c('Z1','Z2','Z3'), 
           'B' = c(100, 200, 500),
           'C' = c(90, 50, 60),
           'D' = c(NA, 50, NA))

newdf <- data.frame('A' = c('Z1','Z2','Z3','Z1','Z2','Z3'), 
                    'B' = c(100, 200, 500, 100, 200, 500),
                    'CD' = c(90, 50, 60, NA, 50, NA))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidyverse` solution:

```
olddf |> 
  pivot_longer(names_to="col", values_to="CD", C:D) |> 
  arrange(col, A) |> 
  select(-col)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  A         B    CD
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Z1      100    90
2 Z2      200    50
3 Z3      500    60
4 Z1      100    NA
5 Z2      200    50
6 Z3      500    NA
```